# How to control order of view activation in Durandal

Tags: durandal

I am building an application with Durandal 2.0.
My shell view looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <header id="nav" data-bind="compose: 'viewmodels/nav', activate: false">
    </header>
     <section id="content" class="main container-fluid" data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance' }, activate: false" style="overflow: auto">
     </section>
    <footer>
        <!--ko compose: {view: 'footer'} --><!--/ko-->
    </footer>
</div>
```

In the nav section, I want to have my tabs and a drop-down list of users (both of which are retrieved from a web service).  Selecting a user from the dropdown will navigate to a new URL which will update the content section.  *(the route looks something like localhost/#user1/tab2).*

- **Problem:**  I need to know the selected user from the nav section before I can retrieve the data for the content section, but the content section is activating before I have retrieved the users.

This is really only an issue for the initial page load, since the user list is only retrieved once.

- Is there a way to tell the content section to wait until the nav section is done loading?
- Is there a better way to go about this than what I'm doing?

The nav activate function looks like this:

```html
function activate(context) {        
    return dataservice.getUsers().then(function () {
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

This activate function gets called first, and dataservice.getUsers() is called, but then the activate function of the content module gets called before the "do stuff" part happens (and before the data from the getUsers call is returned in the dataservice).  Maybe there's a problem with my promises?

**Edit**
I've put together a dFiddle with some actual code that shows what I'm talking about: http://jerrade.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#test/dashboard
The code is here: https://github.com/jerrade/dFiddle-2.0

nav.js

```html
 function activate(context) {
     console.log('Nav View Activated');
     if (vm.impersonateUsername == undefined)
         vm.impersonateUsername = getUsernameFromWindowLocation();

     return dataservice.getPageDetailForEmployee(vm.loggedInUsername, vm).then(function () {
         console.log("Page details retrieved");

         // I want to do something here before the dashboard activates.
     });
  }
```

dashboard.js

```html
 function activate(username) {
        console.log('Dashboard View Activated');
        //vm.username = nav.selectedImpersonateEmployee().Username;        
        return dataservice.getDashboard(nav.impersonateUsername, dashboard);
    }
```

Open the page and watch the console.  You'll see (among other things)

```html
Nav View Activated  
Dashboard View Activated  
Page details retrieved
```

What I really want is for the Page details to be retrieved before the Dashboard view activates.  I've actually rejiggered things so that this isn't currently a problem anymore, but it may crop again down the road.

It doesn't seem like what I'm trying to do should be this complicated.  Unless I'm pounding a square peg into a round hole here?

Comment: No, I think your promises are fine... the `activate` method of nav has nothing to do with the `activate` method of the content module. See my updated answer below for a suggestion of how you can make them "relate" to each other!

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to your fork. The problem now is that you're returning the deferred from the ajax request as your activate method, which resolves as soon as the ajax request returns (rather than once your processing has finished). I couldn't test the code since I couldn't hit your API but I'm pretty sure it should work now.

Comment: I changed the code to return the deferred, but it's still doing the same thing.  Once the code executes dataservice.getPageDetailForEmployee, it switches over to the dashboard activate.  I've mocked my api calls, so you should be able to run it on your machine if you want.

Comment: OK; was more complex than I thought, but the essence of the answer below is still correct. You have to block activation of the dashboard until the employee has loaded. The router will still ACTIVATE the dashboard (since you've told it about the route) but you could prevent it from BINDING with the `if` binding handler (first part of the answer) if you wanted to. Hopefully the updated pull request helps!

Comment: That works, thanks.  It feels like a lot of cruft to add, though.  I think the takeaway is that it's better to try and build things in such a way that everything can happen asynchronously.

Comment: Interested if you ever truly solved this in an elegant fashion.

Comment: @crush No, not really.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to add an observable called something like `isUserLoaded` on your view model. Then, apply an `if` binding around the content section:

```
<div>
    <header id="nav" data-bind="compose: 'viewmodels/nav', activate: false">
    </header>
    <!-- ko if: isUserLoaded -->
     <section id="content" class="main container-fluid" data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance' }, activate: false" style="overflow: auto">
     </section>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <footer>
        <!--ko compose: {view: 'footer'} --><!--/ko-->
    </footer>
</div>
```

Once you've loaded the user, you can update the observable to `true` and your content binding should fire.

**Edit**

If that does't work it sounds like your router must still be resolving the content view model (which may point to a routing problem? Hard to say without seeing your entire solution).

Anyway, if its not a routing issue, then you could employ a solution where your content model returns an unresolved promise from its activate method; then resolve that promise when the user is loaded. For example, something along these lines:

userModel.js:

```
define([], function () {
    // single instance to track the loaded user
    var userModel = {
        selectedUser: ko.observable()
    };

    return userModel;
});
```

navModel.js:

```
define(["dataService", "userModel"], function(dataService, userModel) {
    // view model for the nav bar
    var navModel = {        
        // model definition
    };

    // load the user
    navModel.activate = function() {
        return dataService.getUsers().then(function(response) {
            // Push the user to the userModel
            userModel.selectedUser(response.user);
        });
    };

    return navModel;
});
```

contentModel.js:

```
define(["userModel"], function (userModel) {
    var contentModel = {
        // model definition
    };

    contentModel.activate = function () {
        // Prevent activation until user is resolved
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        var subscription = userModel.selectedUser.subscribe(function (user) {
            if (!user)
                return;

            subscription.dispose();
            deferred.resolve();
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    };

    return contentModel;
});
```

If you don't want to use an observable for the `userModel.selectedUser` property, you could instead use another deferred, or fire an event when the user is loaded, etc etc. Whatever floats your boat!

Comment: That's not working.  Even if I completely cut out that content section from the shell view, the content viewmodel still activates (I assume because the route activates it regardless of what's going on in the shell).

Comment: OK; it may be a routing problem then? But I've added an alternative solution which you could try, hope that helps.

Comment: That wasn't working either.  I've updated my original question with some actual code.  I've gotten around the problem for now.  I'm more just trying to understand if I'm misusing Durandal at this point.